# \t spacing in notepad++'s nppexec

Tags: java, console, notepad++, nppexec

I've written a program in java "CircleDemo" that inevitably does this:

```
System.out.printf("The circle's area \t   is \t %.2f \n", circle.getArea());
System.out.printf("The circle's diameter \t   is \t %.2f \n", circle.getDiameter());
System.out.printf("The circle's circumference is \t %.2f \n", circle.getCircumference());
```

In cmd.exe the display looks like this:

```
The circle's area          is    3.14 
The circle's diameter      is    2.00
The circle's circumference is    6.28
```

Nice, clean formatting.

However, Notepad++'s console (nppexec) prints the same program like this:

```
The circle's area     is    3.14 
The circle's diameter      is    2.00
The circle's circumference is    6.28
```

You can see how the formatting is different. Now, I've played around long enough to find what's causing this is that "\t" prints tabs differently in cmd.exe vs Notepad++'s nppexec.

How could I edit nppexec's "\t" formatting to print "\t" the same as cmd.exe would?

Comment: We use `printf` to avoid `\t` and its problems. You should always specify precisely how many spaces you need. Using `\t` to achieve array formatting is rarely good idea.

Comment: Thank you, @Pshemo, for helping better format my question. I didn't know I could display code so neatly using this "4 spaces" technique.

Comment: No problem, and it is not that it is "4 spaces technique", but `{}` button on editor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid using `\t` to get array format. I would probably simply use

```
System.out.printf("The circle's area          is %.2f %n", circle.getArea() );
System.out.printf("The circle's diameter      is %.2f %n", circle.getDiameter());
System.out.printf("The circle's circumference is %.2f %n", circle.getCircumference());
```

If there is need to have more dynamic solution you could use

```
System.out.printf("The circle's %-13s is %.2f%n", "area", circle.getArea());
```

or if response doesn't need to always start with `The circle's`

```
System.out.printf("%-26s is %.2f%n", "The circle's area",  circle.getArea());
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/jIMg9D)

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for. All solutions output the correct format. Thank you so much, @Pshemo!

Comment: @OlivierPoulin You are right, output is not precisely the same, but shows direction where correct solution can be found. For me this solution is *close enough* to post it as an answer.

Comment: I.... don't know how to "accept" an answer...
I'm new, here. Don't tell nobody, 'kay?
EDIT: Found out I just had to click the pretty check-mark. Thanks for notifying me or I would not have come back here to figure it out!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with not knowing what accepting answer is, or how does it work :) Anyway to find many useful informations about Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites visit official [help], or written by community [Meta FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) and [Stack Overflow FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below example. Do use '-' before the width to ensure left indentation. By default they will be right indented; which may not suit your purpose.

```
    System.out.printf("%-30s %-5s $%.2f\n","The circle's area ", "is" ,circle.getArea());
    System.out.printf("%-30s %-5s $%.2f\n","The circle's diameter ", "is" ,circle.getDiameter());
    System.out.printf("%-30s %-5s $%.2f\n","The circle's circumference ", "is" ,circle.getCircumference());
```

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: I am not sure if `"is"` should be argument. I would probably add it to format instead of `%-5s` since it always exists there. Same about `"The circle's"` part.

Comment: He could, but i thought this format looked more like the original he wanted. Without it, the `is` is awfully close to the numbers.

Comment: But wouldn't `System.out.printf("%-26s is $%.2f\n","The circle's area",  circle.getArea());` or even `System.out.printf("The circle's %-13s is %.2f\n", "area", circle.getArea());` be simpler/clearer? Also we should avoid using spaces in arguments. Their places is in format.